# How to get text inside div

Tags: python, scrapy

Take a look at this webpage:

https://www.michaelkors.com/large-crossgrain-leather-dome-crossbody-bag/_/R-US_32S9SF5C3L?color=2519

I want to get text under details section. When I look at the div it has class detail and text under it. This is the statement I am using:

```
details =  response.xpath('.//div[@class="detail"]/text()').extract()
```

However, it is returning nothing.

Comment: See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the div you're trying to parse does not exist when the page is loaded.
Product data is stored as json inside a script tag, and the div is generated from it using javascript.

This leaves you with a couple of options:

- Parse the javascript and extract the data yourself
- Use a browser (e.g. [scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)) to run the javascript, and parse the resulting HTML

Comment: @Newbie scrapy-splash is well documented and pretty straight forward. If you are having struggles, ask a question regarding the issues you are having with example of what you have tried so far. Please don't just ask for some "useful links" since the documentation is already linked in the answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`class detail` element not found in the page source. Which means it is not found in the response loaded by scrapy request.
Scrapy deals with static requests, it responses all the elements present in the page source.

If the request is a dynamic request, it responses elements present in the inspect element, loaded by javascript, ajax type requests). we should try some other packages along with scrapy to scrape those data.

Examples: `Splash`, `Selenium` etc

In your case you should handle it as dynamic requests.